# Android: Mute ringtone and play custom audio using MediaPlayer

Tags: android

I am not able to mute the incoming call  ring tone and play my own media file using MediaPlayer class.

So far I have tried the following in my Activity that pops on top of incoming call screen, started using a BroadcastReceiver; Activity shows up but audio doesn't play:

```
AudioManager am = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

am.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,true);
```

am.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, 0, 0);

Then I start playing the audio file. The sound plays perfectly in normal mode, so I also set the audio mode to MODE_NORMAL using `am.setMode` method but no luck.

Is there any way around? I am currently mobile and so I could not post full code. If anyone has done this before, a block of code would be a great help. Moreover, I dug up the documentation for AudioManager class and found `setRoute` or similar method which looks good but it has been deprecated long ago so I didn't want to implement it.

Does this approach have different reaults when screen is on or off during an incoming call?

Comment: Please excuse any spelling mistakes as I am posting this question from a mobile drvice, and I don't have connectivity in my PC.

Comment: The issue was resolved with the same method.